# Why does return false not work with AddEventListener and what is Javascript's replacement for preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, return, addeventlistener

I have the following code which is not working

```
var Settings = {
    addConfirmations: function() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll(".bg-red");
        for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
            e[t].addEventListener("click", function() {
                var e = this.getAttribute("title");
                return Settings.confirmation(e)
            })
        }
    },
    confirmation: function(e) {
        if (e === null || e.toString().length === 0) {
            e = "Are you sure you want to proceed?"
        }
        return window.confirm(e);
    }
}
window.onload = Settings.addConfirmations();
```

This code adds a click event to all button with a "bg-red" class, now this does not work because `return false` does not cancel an event if added using `AddEventListener`, I was advised to use `event.preventDefault()` instead but this is not an option as I don't use jQuery. I only use pure javascript.

So, why does return false not work with `AddEventListener` and is there a pure javascript replacement for `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: What makes you think that `event.preventDefault()` is jquery-specific?

Answer (score 4):

`event.preventDefault()` is a part of standard javascript.

jQuery has it's own override version too for compatibility with old IE browsers that did it a different way, but in modern browsers you can use it directly in plain javascript.

So `event.preventDefault()` is the preferred way of cancelling the default behavior from an event handler added with `.addEventListener()`.

[MDN documentation for `event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

[W3C specification for `event.preventDefault()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault)

---

`return false` is simply not a feature of `addEventListener()`.  It works from event handlers specified in the HTML with attributes like `onclick=...`, but not for event handlers added using `addEventListener()`.  I can't speak to why the original designers made this choice, but that is the way it is.